# issue with updating package dependencies

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, package, dependencies

what does it even mean? I tried to update the package version due to some issue I faced.I thought it would solve the issue.But now I am stuck here.I don't understand why it says that it depends on the other package.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the version with any like `image_cropper: any`. Flutter will choose compatible version.

Then `flutter pub get` and  then open the `pubspec.lock` and took the version number there.

Also you can try

```dart
image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
```

Comment: Thanks man. I used the dependency override solution.it solved the issue.